# Is it possible to program a "selectable" number of devices without actually hardcoding every possible scenario?

Tags: c, visual-c++

I have been working on a project over the past 6 months creating a program to control some machinery.  The software controls some servos, and other bits mostly via serial communication.

It is currently programmed in ANSI C99 in the Lab Windows IDE, along with some of its included libraries.  As the project continues, there are many different variations on "how many" servos are needed for each build.  This ends up requiring custom coding for each one.  I feel the core logic could still be programmed this way, and just put into a dll if need be, and the rest programmed in something else like C++ if need be.

Due to the fact that each servo needs to be individually controllable, is there really a way to allow a user to select how many they want during an initial setup?

I know it is simple to create a UI element to allow a selection, but how would you go about dynamically creating new UI elements, and variables associated with that UI element for individual control?  I think this could work in an interpreted language, where you could have a function literally write out new code after the user makes a selection, but I don't know how to achieve this in a compiled language.

I am currently just researching the feasibility of moving this direction at all, and would greatly appreciate any thoughts or input. If it is possible, I think I just need a basic example of how to go about this sort of problem.

The only way I can personally think of achieving this is to literally program out every possible scenario, but we are talking potentially about 50 variations, so I am really hoping there is a more efficient way to go about this.

If you have any questions for me in order to better answer, please feel free to ask!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's more difficult, but far from impossible, in a compiled language.  Creating, for example, a new instance of a form class and and any associated gunge to control a new servo instance would be a one-liner in many OO languages, though streaming out the form, with it's configured parameters, and subsequent streaming back in, may be an annoying complication.

Comment: Which graphics framework are you using? Does it have a [layout manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layout_manager)?

Comment: The graphics framework currently implemented is the integrated one with Lab Windows; UIR, or National Instruments User Interface Resource.  There is a drag and drop editor, as well as an associated header file that is really just a list of macros for each element.  For example: |          #define    TABPANEL_STRING    1